# Upgrading Production .NET 4.5.1 to 4.6.1: Is reboot or IIS paused during .NET setup?

Tags: .net, iis

I suppose the real question is:

Can a production Win2012 box running production .NET app under IIS, be updated from .NET 4.5.1 to 4.6.1 during the day / hot, or will there be app impact during the .NET install?

And is there any difference in this regard Win2012 vs Win2012-R2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on experience:

1) Yes, a reboot will be required, the .NET installer prompts for it.

and

2) Running apps may impacted

Have not tried shutting down IIS before update to see if that reduces impact. Suspect that reboot will still be nec.

Bottom line: This update will interrupt IIS... It will impact a hot / production server. There will be a period of downtime on this instance for the reboot.

Comment: I've had a similar experience but with one caveat... The server may go down but there's no reason the _site_ should go down. If you don't already have either a hot backup or (better) multiple nodes balancing load, you should improve your setup immediately. One server is never sufficient to guarantee uptime. Once you've got 2 servers, upgrading becomes trivial (as does dealing with outages, assuming different physical locations and network providers)

Comment: @Basic Fair call. Post enhanced.

Comment: As 4.x are in-place upgrade, the processes using the old bits must shut down for the new bits to take effect. Thus, you should never apply it to a hot machine. The other comment tells the truth.